# Saving plot with a user input

Tags: python, matplotlib

def my_Plot(A):
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

```
# Change color of text
plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'black'
save = input("Dosya adi ne olarak kaydedilsin?")
# icerideki yuvarlak
my_circle=plt.Circle( (0,0), 0.7, color='white')
size = [3, 3, 3]
# Pieplot + circle on it
plt.pie(size, labels=A, colors=['cornflowerblue', 'skyblue', 'lightsteelblue'])
p=plt.gcf()
p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)
plt.savefig(['userinput or get as a function input.jpg'], dpi= 300)
```

So I create a function that create plot and I want to save it with different names. So how can I use plt.savefig with user input filename or with the input in function?

Comment: it would be great to see what you have done first. share your code and we can guide you better.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def my_Plot(A):
    user_input= input()
    plt_name2= f'{user_input}.jpg'

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

    # Change color of text
    plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'black'
    save = input("Dosya adi ne olarak kaydedilsin?")
    # icerideki yuvarlak
    my_circle=plt.Circle( (0,0), 0.7, color='white')
    size = [3, 3, 3]
  # Pieplot + circle on it
    plt.pie(size, labels=A, colors=['cornflowerblue', 'skyblue', 'lightsteelblue'])
    p=plt.gcf()
    p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)
    plt.savefig(plt_name2, dpi= 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

For user input you could do this:

```
def my_Plot(A):
    fig = plt.figure() 
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

    # Change color of text
    plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'black'
    save_name = input("Dosya adi ne olarak kaydedilsin?")
    ...
    p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)
    plt.savefig(['{}.jpg'.format(save_name)], dpi= 300)
```

And then as a parameter:

```
def my_Plot(A, save_name):
    ...
    p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)
    plt.savefig(['{}.jpg'.format(save_name)], dpi= 300)
```